# play framework - Not found error for an existing route

Tags: routes, playframework

I am using the http.path property in application.conf to serve the play app from a different path. So in application conf, I have

http.path=/sales/

When I try to access http://localhost:9000/sales/, I am getting the following error.

```
Not found

GET /sales/

These routes have been tried, in this order :

   1. GET       /@documentation/cheatsheet/{category}             PlayDocumentation.cheatSheet
   2. GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/files/{name}     PlayDocumentation.file
   3. GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/images/{name}    PlayDocumentation.image
   4. GET       /@documentation/modules/{module}/{id}             PlayDocumentation.page
   5. GET       /@documentation/files/{name}                      PlayDocumentation.file
   6. GET       /@documentation/images/{name}                     PlayDocumentation.image
   7. GET       /@documentation/{id}                              PlayDocumentation.page
   8. GET       /@documentation/?                                 PlayDocumentation.index
   9. *         /sales/                                           Application.index
  10. GET       /sales/login                                 Secure.login
  11. POST      /sales/login                                 Secure.authenticate
  12. GET       /sales/logout                                Secure.logout
```

**Note** : In my routes file, I am not prepending the routes with '/sales'. It is automatically added to each route.

I am not sure why I the '/sales/' route is not recognized. If I give the route '/sales/login' or any other route it works.

**Additional Info** : In the Secure module, I have made changes in two places to set the default URL as '/sales/' instead of '/'.

The changes are

flash.put("url",play.Play.configuration.get("http.path"));

url = String.valueOf(play.Play.configuration.get("http.path"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the trailing slash from the http.path setting

```
http.path=/sales
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped a lot. Especially when in documentation that slash is... http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/configuration